# PDO Object inside class getting Warning: Missing argument 1 for

Tags: php, pdo

I am getting this error trying to connect to DB,

having config.php file where pdo object is being created:

```
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $opt);
```

after that inside the user.php I have a class stating the following:

```
require_once('config.php');
class USER {

    private $conn;          

    public function __construct($pdo) {     
        $this->conn = $pdo;

    }
```

The object seems to be available inside the user.php file but not inside the class. Any suggestion how to overcome this ?

error is: **Warning: Missing argument 1 for USER::__construct()**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you calling your `USER` class? `new USER`?

Comment: `require_once('class/user.php');
$user = new USER();`

Comment: You're not passing `$pdo`. You need `new USER($pdo)`.

Comment: that worked, place it as an answer and I will accept it. Thank you!